VictoriaMetrics metrics collision
We have the following setup: opentelemetry java agent (v2.0.0) sends metrics to VictoriaMetrcis through otel-collector.  With Prometheus everything works fine, but Victoria deletes label "instance" that is kubernetes pod name and we have only one record for the same metric with incorrect value.
For example:
We have the metric "http_server_requests_seconds_count". With label "instance" there are two records (because of two pods):
{application="app", instance="402032de-f645-4ee7-9747-c43f2022ee19",..., outcome="SUCCESS"}
{application="app", instance="d8743558-a0e7-4a1c-94c8-4999ffd2255e",..., outcome="SUCCESS"}
But without "instance" there is only one record:
{application="app",..., outcome="SUCCESS"}
and this recod has completely wrong value (let's say, we have 7 http requests, but it shows 21, then 34, then 62, so it increases without any visible reason).
My question is why it does'n calculate metrics properly? What's the mechanism behind it? Am I right that it's kind of 'collision'? What's the best practice for gathering metrcis from multiple pods? Divide it by pod names / ids?
We've solved the problem using different version of opentelemetry java agent, 2.7.0. Label "instance" showed up and we can divide metrics by pods. But there are still questions.

VictoriaMetrics stores what you send to it. It could drop labels only if --maxLabelsPerTimeseries limit is exceeded (30, by default). Otherwise, there should be no drops. If changing java agent version helped to solve the problem, then it is likely and agent problem, not VictoriaMetrics problem.
